# How create String primary key with GeoTools?

Tags: java, geotools

I'm developing a gis app with [geotools 19-SNAPSHOT](http://www.geotools.org/). I want to get some gis data from another app. After getting data, save them in local db. Received data has a String primary key as follow:

```
@Id
private String code;
```

First, I want to get `featureType`,then create table and finally getting data and save them.

When I create a table with `SimpleFeatureType`, it create int `fid` primary key, But I want to it create String primary key named `code`. **How Can I do it with GeoTools**?

**Update**:

I create table as follow:

```
SimpleFeatureType getReceivedFeatureType()
{
     return getDataStore(cfgs).getSchema("myTableName");
}

DataStore getDataStore(cfgs)
{
     URI uri = new URI("db-url");
     Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap();

     params.put("dbtype", "postgis");
     params.put("host", url.getHost());
     //Other Db Connection Configs

     return DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
}

store = getDataStore(cfgs);
SimpleFeatureType sft = getReceivedFeatureType();
store.createSchema(sft);
```

Comment: we need to see more of your code, especially the part creating the schema (featureType) and the features.

Comment: @IanTurton I updated it.

Comment: You are still missing the feature creation code

Comment: @IanTurton first, I want to create correct table, then add features. (if the name of primary key be `fid` and its type be int, my code save features correctly). My problem is creating table with special primary key.

Comment: hello @Morteza Malvandi, I have the same issue, did you find a solution? thank you

Comment: @AnasBenMansour unfortunately no.